# Combine IDs from many different tables in to a single column within a seperate table

Tags: sql

I have a database that has different financial article tables for each article type. 
For example:

`fa_meds_01` with the ID column name `FA_MED_ID`, 
`fa_uniforms_02` with the ID column name `FA_U_ID`, 
`fa_trips_03` with the ID column name `FA_T_ID`, 
`fa_experts_04` with the ID column name `FA_E_ID`.

These IDs are going to be named differently like `MED1`, `U1`, `T1`, etc..

I want to store all of these in to a single table called `t_fin_articles` with the ID column named `A_ID` which is going to be referenced to a general expenses journal with all the other details.

So expected result should be the table `t_fin_articles` showing under `A_ID` IDs those financial article tables.

How would one go about doing such a task? Or maybe those different tables could be referenced to the general expenses journal directed?

Comment: Don't forget the question! (And take a look at [mcve] too.)

Comment: Typically you would use inheritance for this kind of issue. It sounds like the section in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/1048425) about class inheritance would be most appropriate. In summary, you would generate unique IDs in your table `t_fin_articles`, then you would re-use these IDs in your other tables, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the ids from different tables using union operation. An example would be like below:

```
select
    FA_MED_ID as id
  from
    fa_meds_01
union all
    select
      FA_U_ID as id
    from
      fa_uniforms_02
union all
    select
      FA_T_ID as id
    from
      fa_trips_03
union all
    select
      FA_E_ID as id
    from
      fa_experts_04
```

add any other required fields also to each select statement with a common column alias so that the union will work fine.